# An interesting identity involving the abundancy index of divisors of odd perfect numbers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of divisors of the positive integer $x$.

A number $y$ is said to be perfect if $\sigma(y)=2y$.

Denote the abundancy index of $z$ by $I(z)=\sigma(z)/z$.

Euler proved that an *odd perfect number* $N$, if one exists, must necessarily have the form $N = q^k n^2$ where $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

While considering the difference
$$I(n^2) - I(q^k)$$
for $k=1$, I came across the interesting identity
$$\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(I(n^2)-I(q)\bigg)=\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(\frac{q^2 - 2q - 1}{q(q+1)}\bigg)=\frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q^2 (q+1)^2}.$$
This *is interesting* because of
$$I(n^2)+I(q)=\frac{2q}{q+1}+\frac{q+1}{q}=\frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q+1)}=q(q+1)\bigg(\frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q^2 (q+1)^2}\bigg)$$
so that we have the *identity* (or *differential equation* (?))
$$q(q+1)\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(I(n^2)-I(q)\bigg)=I(n^2)+I(q).$$

Two questions:

> **[1]** Is there a simple explanation for why the identity (or differential equation (?)) holds?
>
> **[2]** Are there any other identities that could be derived in a similar fashion?

**Update (July 25, 2020 - 10:15 AM Manila time)**

I tried computing the derivative
$$\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(I(n^2)+I(q)\bigg)$$
and I got
$$q(q+1)\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(I(n^2)+I(q)\bigg)=q(q+1)\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(\frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q+1)}\bigg)=q(q+1)\bigg(\frac{q^2 - 2q - 1}{q^2 (q+1)^2}\bigg)=I(n^2)-I(q).$$

Comment: $I$ is defined on a discrete set, the natural numbers. Differentiation requires functions defined on a continuum. How are you extending $I$ to a continuum so that you can perform this differentination?

Comment: Apologies for the late revert, @PaulSinclair.  Since $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then we have
$$I(q^k)I(n^2)=2,$$
so that both
$$I(n^2)+I(q^k)$$
and
$$I(n^2)-I(q^k)$$
may be written entirely in terms of $q$ and $k$.  (I will omit the details.)

Then for computing the derivative
$$\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(I(n^2) - I(q^k)\bigg)$$
I refer you to the following [link on the Arithmetic Derivative](http://oeis.org/wiki/Arithmetic_derivative#Arithmetic_derivative_of_natural_numbers).

So basically, that is how I would define it.

Comment: That is a concept I haven't encountered before. All I can say is I think the wiki article is wise to have spurned Leibnitz's $\frac d{dq}$ notation. While that notation is highly suggestive of actual behavior in analysis, here I do not see it as being anything other than mis-leading.

Comment: This is only an impression I get, so please don't take it too strongly, but it seems you are taking something specific to a very specialized case and presuming it to have some more far-reaching significance. For example, someone might say "I notice that for $f(x) = x^2$, and letting $x = 2, y = 1$, it follows that $f(x + y) = xf(x) + yf(y)$. Is there any explanation why? Can we prove other identities similarly?" to which the answers are "yes, it is a coincidence" and "yes, you can search for other coincidences."

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @PaulSinclair!  However, I am not discouraged from pursuing this further.

Indeed, I tried computing the derivative
$$\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(I(n^2)+I(q)\bigg)$$
and I got
$$\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(I(n^2)+I(q)\bigg)=\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(\frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q+1)}\bigg)=\frac{q^2 - 2q - 1}{q^2 (q+1)^2}=q(q+1)\bigg(I(n^2)-I(q)\bigg).$$
Here is the [WolframAlpha computational verification](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Differentiate+%283q%5E2+%2B+2q+%2B+1%29%2F%28q%28q%2B1%29%29+with+respect+to+q).

Comment: You seem to be mixing up the analytic and arithmetic derivatives. The two are not always the same. In particular, it is obvious that the arithmetic derivative does not satisfy $(a + b)' = a' + b'$. If it did, it would be trivial, since $1' = 0$. Since distributing over addition is a key property of the analytic derivative, this tells you that they do not behave the same in general.

Comment: I meant to say
$$q(q+1)\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(I(n^2)+I(q)\bigg)=q(q+1)\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(\frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q+1)}\bigg)=q(q+1)\bigg(\frac{q^2 - 2q - 1}{q^2 (q+1)^2}\bigg)=I(n^2)-I(q)$$
in my last equation above, @PaulSinclair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is nothing too special about the identities, as we shall soon see.**

Hereinafter, we let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, and we assume that the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture that $k=1$ holds true.  Also, we denote the *abundancy index* of the positive integer $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$, where $\sigma(x)$ is the classical *sum of divisors* of $x$.

We compute:

$$\frac{d}{dq}(I(n^2) + I(q))=\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(\frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q+1)}\bigg)=\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(3 - \frac{q - 1}{q(q + 1)}\bigg)=\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(\frac{-1}{q+1}+\frac{1}{q(q+1)}\bigg)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(\frac{-2}{q+1}+\frac{1}{q}\bigg)=\frac{2}{(q+1)^2}-\frac{1}{q^2}= \frac{2q^2 - (q+1)^2}{(q(q+1))^2}$$

But
$$I(n^2) - I(q) = \frac{2q}{q+1} - \frac{q+1}{q} = \frac{2q^2 - (q+1)^2}{q(q+1)}.$$

Similarly, we obtain:

$$\frac{d}{dq}(I(n^2) - I(q))=\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(\frac{q^2 - 2q - 1}{q(q+1)}\bigg)=\frac{d}{dq}(I(n^2) + I(q) - 2I(q))$$
$$=\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(3 - \frac{q - 1}{q(q + 1)} - \frac{2(q+1)}{q}\bigg)=\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(\frac{-1}{q+1}+\frac{1}{q(q+1)}+\frac{-2}{q}-2\bigg)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(\frac{-2}{q+1}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{-2}{q}-2\bigg)=\frac{d}{dq}\bigg(\frac{-2}{q+1}-\frac{1}{q}-2\bigg)=\frac{2}{(q+1)^2}+\frac{1}{q^2}$$
$$=\frac{2q^2 + (q+1)^2}{(q(q+1))^2}.$$

But
$$I(n^2)+I(q)=\frac{2q}{q+1}+\frac{q+1}{q}=\frac{2q^2 + (q+1)^2}{q(q+1)}.$$

In the above computations, we have used the identity
$$\frac{1}{q(q+1)}=\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{q+1}.$$